# Obtener la url de una página a partir de la url json

Tags: json

tengo una pregunta de aprendiz y por ello pido de antemano disculpas.
Abro una página web en Chrome, y al entrar en Herramientas para desarrolladores/XHR-Headers-Request URL para obtener el URL completo de la página veo que en realidad se trata de una solicitud HTTP GET y  la respuesta de la API es un JSON. Mi pregunta sin saber programar es si se puede obtener de forma fácil el URL que abre la página en cuestión en Chrome a partir del URL JSON que se informa en Headers.

Muchas gracias
Francisco

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Qué errores tienes? Donde está el [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen) que se menciona en el [tour] y en [ask].